"kpc.config" sysctl call returns -1 in ibireme's "kpc_demo" on M4 Apple Silicon (macOS Sequoia 15.2), but works fine on M1/M2
I’m using this gist by ibireme (https://gist.github.com/ibireme/173517c208c7dc333ba962c1f0d67d12) to inspect Apple Silicon PMU counters. On M1 and M2 MacBook Pros running macOS Sequoia 15.2, everything works as expected. However, when trying the same approach on an M4 MacBook Pro (also on Sequoia 15.2), the code fails with the following error message:
loaded db: as4-1 (Apple silicon)
number of fixed counters: 2
number of configurable counters: 8
Failed set kpc config: -1.

I used LLVM to debug and found that the error originates in the kpc_set_config function. It turns out that the system call "kpc.config" returns -1, which means an error.
I wonder if there is any known solutions or is there anything I can do to solve this? Thank you in advance!
Below is the assembly of kpc_set_config disassembled by llvm:
kperf`kpc_set_config:
    0x1d3564cd4 <+0>:   pacibsp 
    0x1d3564cd8 <+4>:   sub    sp, sp, #0x60
    0x1d3564cdc <+8>:   stp    x24, x23, [sp, #0x20]
    0x1d3564ce0 <+12>:  stp    x22, x21, [sp, #0x30]
    0x1d3564ce4 <+16>:  stp    x20, x19, [sp, #0x40]
    0x1d3564ce8 <+20>:  stp    x29, x30, [sp, #0x50]
    0x1d3564cec <+24>:  add    x29, sp, #0x50
    0x1d3564cf0 <+28>:  mov    x19, x1
    0x1d3564cf4 <+32>:  mov    x20, x0
    0x1d3564cf8 <+36>:  str    wzr, [sp, #0xc]
    0x1d3564cfc <+40>:  str    w0, [sp, #0x1c]
    0x1d3564d00 <+44>:  mov    w8, #0x4 ; =4 
    0x1d3564d04 <+48>:  str    x8, [sp, #0x10]
    0x1d3564d08 <+52>:  adrp   x0, 4
    0x1d3564d0c <+56>:  add    x0, x0, #0x9af ; "kpc.config_count"
    0x1d3564d10 <+60>:  add    x1, sp, #0xc
    0x1d3564d14 <+64>:  add    x2, sp, #0x10
    0x1d3564d18 <+68>:  add    x3, sp, #0x1c
    0x1d3564d1c <+72>:  mov    w4, #0x4 ; =4 
    0x1d3564d20 <+76>:  bl     0x1d35687a0    ; symbol stub for: sysctlbyname
    0x1d3564d24 <+80>:  mov    w21, #-0x1 ; =-1 
    0x1d3564d28 <+84>:  tbnz   w0, #0x1f, 0x1d3564d98 ; <+196>
    0x1d3564d2c <+88>:  ldr    w8, [sp, #0xc]
    0x1d3564d30 <+92>:  cbz    w8, 0x1d3564d98 ; <+196>
    0x1d3564d34 <+96>:  lsl    w23, w8, #3
    0x1d3564d38 <+100>: add    w21, w23, #0x8
    0x1d3564d3c <+104>: mov    x0, x21
    0x1d3564d40 <+108>: mov    w1, #0x3c4a ; =15434 
    0x1d3564d44 <+112>: movk   w1, #0x1d54, lsl #16
    0x1d3564d48 <+116>: bl     0x1d35686e0    ; symbol stub for: malloc_type_malloc
    0x1d3564d4c <+120>: cbz    x0, 0x1d3564d94 ; <+192>
    0x1d3564d50 <+124>: mov    x22, x0
    0x1d3564d54 <+128>: mov    w8, w20
    0x1d3564d58 <+132>: str    x8, [x0], #0x8
    0x1d3564d5c <+136>: mov    x1, x19
    0x1d3564d60 <+140>: mov    x2, x23
    0x1d3564d64 <+144>: bl     0x1d35686f0    ; symbol stub for: memcpy
    0x1d3564d68 <+148>: adrp   x0, 4
    0x1d3564d6c <+152>: add    x0, x0, #0x9a4 ; "kpc.config"
    0x1d3564d70 <+156>: mov    x1, #0x0 ; =0 
    0x1d3564d74 <+160>: mov    x2, #0x0 ; =0 
    0x1d3564d78 <+164>: mov    x3, x22
    0x1d3564d7c <+168>: mov    x4, x21
    0x1d3564d80 <+172>: bl     0x1d35687a0    ; symbol stub for: sysctlbyname
    0x1d3564d84 <+176>: mov    x21, x0
    0x1d3564d88 <+180>: mov    x0, x22
    0x1d3564d8c <+184>: bl     0x1d35686a0    ; symbol stub for: free
    0x1d3564d90 <+188>: b      0x1d3564d98    ; <+196>
    0x1d3564d94 <+192>: mov    w21, #-0x1 ; =-1 
    0x1d3564d98 <+196>: mov    x0, x21
    0x1d3564d9c <+200>: ldp    x29, x30, [sp, #0x50]
    0x1d3564da0 <+204>: ldp    x20, x19, [sp, #0x40]
    0x1d3564da4 <+208>: ldp    x22, x21, [sp, #0x30]
    0x1d3564da8 <+212>: ldp    x24, x23, [sp, #0x20]
    0x1d3564dac <+216>: add    sp, sp, #0x60
    0x1d3564db0 <+220>: retab

